# Replay Cloudwatch logs shipped to a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda subscribed to many cloudwatch log groups, to process/index/analyse those logs.

Everything works fine, but I'd like to replay a large amount of old logs with this lambda. 
I'm trying to do it by fetching logs via the `aws logs get-log-events` CLI but I can't find an easy way to do it because of the way data is structured.

First, the lambda is invoked with an encoded/gzip blob in a json `{"awslogs": {"data": "H4sIAAAAAAA ....` I can easily manage that, but the blob itself is expected to be structured this way:

```
{
    "messageType": "DATA_MESSAGE",
    "owner": "...",
    "logGroup": "/aws/lambda/...",
    "logStream": "2019/08/02/[$LATEST]...",
    "subscriptionFilters": [
        "..."
    ],
    "logEvents": [
        {
            "id": "34402224585553617062605662326569493632889831387406598144",
            "timestamp": 1564703999832,
            "message": "..."
        },
        ...
```

And the output of `aws logs get-log-events` is nowhere near this structure.
I could try to rebuild this by myself, but this is going to be tedious. And some fields are missing (eg. `logEvents.id`)

Am I missing some other easier way to replay logs to my lambda ?